# Illegal chars exception trying to load from url with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to load a web page using this code:

```
Dim DirectPage As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
DirectPage.Load(mUrl)
```

`mUrl` is a string and contains the full url of the page.

The url is correct!
I tryed to copy/paste it into my browser and it showed the correct web page.

I also tryed with `WebRequest.Create(mUrl)` and it worked.
So my questions are:
1) Why `HtmlAgilityPack` doesn't accept `mUrl`?
2) What are the "illegal chars"? Is there a list of them somewhere?
3) Is there a way to make `HtmlAgilityPack` code to work correclty?

Comment: That's because `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument` the `Load` method takes the actual `html` ***not*** a `URL`. If you want to load a page use `HtmlWeb.Load(url)`... **OR** `Dim wC As New WebClient() DirectPage.Load(wC.OpenRead(mUrl))`

Comment: @Codexer Thanks, It works! If you post it as answer I'll accept ;)

Comment: I was posting as you sent this comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.Load` method takes the actual `html` not a URL. If you want to load a page use `HtmlWeb.Load(url)`

**Another Option**

```
 Dim wC As New WebClient() 
 DirectPage.Load(wC.OpenRead(mUrl))
```